# Loading External Text file into a Flash - URL not loading

Tags: flash, actionscript, flashdevelop, loadvars

**Flash ActionScript**

myData = new LoadVars();

myData.onLoad = function() {

myText_txt.text = this.myVariable;

};

myData.load("http://www.myserver.com/test/myText.txt");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you by chance getting a failed (http404) call to a crossdomain.xml file on the server? Check out: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply - myData = new LoadVars();

myData.onLoad = function() {

myText_txt.text = this.myVariable;

};

myData.load("http://www.myserver.com/test/crossdomain.xml");

Comment: ------------------------------------------------------------------- <?xml version="1.0"?>
  

     <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
  

     <cross-domain-policy>
  
  

     <allow-access-from domain="http://www.myserver.com/test/myText.txt" />
  

     </cross-domain-policy> --------------------------------------Am I right?

Comment: Close; you want the domain to be the DOMAIN where the request is coming from. Ie, where the HTML SHOWING this Flash is. Likely that is still "myserver", so it would be:  domain="myserver.com". You can also use  domain="*" if you want it to be read from anywhere.